# admob clicks no longer reporting in IOS

Tags: admob

i add the "skadnetwork" and i see after weeks the report admob clicks stuck on 0 clicks
i see have more pepole with this problem but dont have any soultion.

can please someone help how to fix that?

(i try contac us with admob but have them problem and cant send them message and i found this them see all its ok but its not..)

https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/CBjqRuT0VHc

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.  I rolled back to SDK v7 to fix.